# Web-scraping multiple pages in R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, while-loop

I am trying to scrap this website and extract content from multiple pages. I used a while loop to increase the page number every time but it is not working. All it does is duplicate the same content from page 0, as opposed to getting the content from the other pages (in the example below 3 times).

I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://npin.cdc.gov/search?=type%3Aorganization&page="

# counter:
e <- 0

result <- data.frame(org_name = as.integer(), 
                     services = as.character(), 
                     item = as.character(),
                     street = as.character(),
                     city = as.character(), 
                     state = as.character())
while (e <= 3) {
  
  cat(".")
  
  new_page <-
    read_html(
      # change the page number with each iteration of the loop
      sprintf(
        base_url,
        e
      )
    )
  
  services <- new_page %>% html_nodes(".services-fieldset")
  org_name <- new_page %>% html_nodes(".block-field-blocknodeorganizationtitle") %>% html_text2()
  street <- new_page |> html_nodes(".address-line1") |> html_text2()
  city <- new_page |> html_nodes(".locality") |> html_text2()
  state <- new_page |> html_nodes(".administrative-area") |> html_text2()
  zip <- new_page |> html_nodes(".postal-code") |> html_text2()


  new_result <- for (i in 1:length(services)) {
    temp <- services[i] %>% html_nodes(".field__items")
    for (j in 2:length(temp)) {
      label <- temp[j] %>% html_nodes(".field-label") %>% html_text() %>% gsub(":", "", .)
      items <- temp[j] %>% html_nodes(".field__item") %>% html_text()
      result[nrow(result) +1, ] <- c(org_name[i], label, paste0(items, collapse = ","))
    }
  }


  # append each iteration of the data to the main table:
  result <-
    rbind(
      result,
      new_result
    )

  # increase counter
  e <- e + 1
  
}

result |> tibble()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a few issues here. You already fixed the non-existing `new_york_raw` object, but it still doesn't make sense to grow `result` inside the loop, and then bind that to `new_result` which is the output of a `for` loop, i.e. `NULL`.

Probably the biggest issue is that you're creating your URL via `sprintf(base_url, e)` which doesn't do what you think it does -- you probably want `paste0(base_url, e)` or similar.

A combined fix could look like the following. I replaced the loops by `do.call` and `*apply` which makes not too much difference for performance but is a more natural way in R to bind data together.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://npin.cdc.gov/search?=type%3Aorganization&page="

all_e <- 0:3

result <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(all_e, \(e) {
  new_page <- read_html(paste0(base_url, e))  ## Use correct URL
  
  services <- html_nodes(new_page, ".services-fieldset")
  orgs <- html_nodes(new_page, ".block-field-blocknodeorganizationtitle") |> html_text2()
  streets <- html_nodes(new_page, ".address-line1") |> html_text2()
  cities <- html_nodes(new_page, ".locality") |> html_text2()
  states <- html_nodes(new_page, ".administrative-area") |> html_text2()
  zips <- html_nodes(new_page, ".postal-code") |> html_text2()
  
  do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(services), \(i) {
    tmp <- html_nodes(services[i], ".field__items")
    cbind(
      data.frame(
        Org=orgs[i],
        Street=streets[i],
        City=cities[i],
        State=states[i],
        Zip=zips[i]
      ),
      do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp[-1], \(t) {
        label <- html_nodes(t, ".field-label") |> html_text() |> gsub(":", "", x=_)
        items <- html_nodes(t, ".field__item") |> html_text()
        c("Label"=label, "Items"=paste0(items, collapse = ","))
      }))
    )
  }))
}))

result |> tibble()
```

As a minor pet peeve I have no idea why one would write `x <- y |> f()` rather than just `x <- f(y)`?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @PBulls! but this code is not running, it seems to have a bug.

Comment: @Mando I replaced a `magrittr` pipe with the base one without updating the placeholder, please try again (should be fixed).

Comment: ....wait it is still not showing the other columns: street, city, state, and zip.

Comment: @Mando you were not returning these in your original code either, I've updated again.